# For what potentials is the heat operator with a potential term hypoelliptic?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, laplacian, heat-equation

If $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami (negatively defined) operator, is it possible to describe the class of smooth potentials $V :M \to \Bbb R$ that make the heat operator $\partial_t - \Delta + V$ on $(0,\infty) \times M$ hypoelliptic? If this is too complicated (as I suspect it is), then is it possible to impose reasonable sufficient conditions on $(M,g)$ and $V$ in order to obtain this hypoellipticity?

Comment: Inuitively, how could such an operator *not* be hypoelliptic, given that the leading term is elliptic?  If $V$ is very wild, you might have problems with existence of solutions, but it seems to me that if they exist they should be smooth.

Comment: @NateEldredge: $\Delta$ is elliptic on $M$, but not on $(0,\infty) \times M$. Also, the "true" Schrödinger operator $\Bbb i \partial_t + \Delta$ is known to not be hypoelliptic. Or maybe I'm just not following you.